# Does py2app support python3?

Tags: py2app

I've developed an application in windows using python 3.1.1 with pyqt 4.6.. 
Just want to know that can i make it as a stand alone application in Mac OS using py2app?? Does py2app support python 3.1.1.

I'm posting the question here bcoz. it's not particularly mentioned in any of their documents..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `py2app`, but [`cx_Freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) works with Python 3.

Comment: Thanks carl.. I'm already using cx-freeze to freeze python scripts in windows and linux.. I've tested it and working fine.. But i'm looking for Mac?? Is there any package available to freeze python 3.x scripts in Mac??

Comment: cx_Freeze is supposed to work on any platform python does, right?  Is there some problem getting it to work on OS X?

Comment: Thanks carl for your info.. But i have one more question.. Can we make .dmg images out of our python scripts in mac?? Bcoz. py2app allows us to do so..

Comment: @Jebagnanadas, You can use `hdiutil` to make disk images pretty easily.

Comment: +1 for three help file answers.  @Jebagnanadas, you could dish out some karma.

Answer (score 1):

There is experimental Python 3 support since [py2app 0.5](http://pythonhosted.org//py2app/changelog.html#py2app-0-5)